# Any way to access DAYWISE Facebook ad insights using python and add the response data to an mysql database table?

Tags: python, facebook-graph-api, python-requests, facebook-insights

I was able to access the ads using Postman API and got a python-requests code using the ***'Code'*** option from the Postman app.
But the time_increment is working in a few cases.
When the time_increment clause works I got a JSON response which I'm unable to convert into a pandas dataframe.

My code looks like this:

```
import requests

url = "https://graph.facebook.com/v5.0/act_<------id------>/insights?fields=campaign_id,campaign_name,clicks,unique_clicks,reach,spend,impressions,cost_per_unique_click,purchase_roas,website_purchase_roas&time_range={\"since\":\"2019-12-01\",\"until\":\"2019-12-07\"}&time_increment(1)&limit(200)"

payload = {}
headers = {
  'Authorization': 'Bearer <access_token>'
}

response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, data = payload)

res = response.json()
print(res)
```

When I run the above code I don't get the needed columns like campaign_id, campaign_name, etc.
And neither the time_increment clause works.

Any solution is highly appreciated. Please!
I was stuck here for the good part of the last week.

My output is :

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "clicks": "45547",
            "unique_clicks": "63257",
            "reach": "4269850",
            "spend": "69403.83",
            "impressions": "8525031",
            "cost_per_unique_click": "13.57562",
            "purchase_roas": [
                {
                    "action_type": "xxxxxxxxx",
                    "value": "1.571284"
                }
            ],
            "website_purchase_roas": [
                {
                    "action_type": "yyyyyy.zzzzzzz",
                    "value": "4.587928"
                }
            ],
            "date_start": "2019-12-01",
            "date_stop": "2019-12-07"
        }
    ],
    "paging": {
        "cursors": {
            "before": "MAZDZD",
            "after": "MAZDZD"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: check the below code and let me know if it's works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import requests

payload = {}

headers = {
    'Authorization': 'Bearer <access_token>'
}

r = requests.get(
    "https://graph.facebook.com/v5.0/act_<------id------>/insights?fields=campaign_id,campaign_name,clicks,unique_clicks,reach,spend,impressions,cost_per_unique_click,purchase_roas,website_purchase_roas&time_range={\"since\":\"2019-12-01\",\"until\":\"2019-12-07\"}&time_increment(1)&limit(200)", headers=headers, json=payload).json()


print(r)
```

Comment: Thank you for the code but It doesn't work as needed.

Comment: This is the output i got:   
{'data': [{'clicks': '81427', 'unique_clicks': '63887', 'reach': '4277250', 'spend': '869403.83', 'impressions': '8605031', 'cost_per_unique_click': '13.608462', 'purchase_roas': [{'action_type': 'omni_purchase', 'value': '2.886286'}], 'website_purchase_roas': [{'action_type': 'offsite_conversion.fb_pixel_purchase', 'value': '2.886286'}], 'date_start': '2019-12-01', 'date_stop': '2019-12-07'}], 'paging': {'cursors': {'before': 'MAZDZD', 'after': 'MAZDZD'}}}

Comment: No Campaign ID or Names and the data is for the whole date range.

Comment: @kickbat6 i think that you need to read `postman` documentation to filter out what you looking for. as i don't have access to any of your stuff or your configurations

Comment: Had to dive deep into the response to check for the dates